# How to create a nest list or a tree view from a flat list based on value condition?

Tags: python

I am working on a problem that given a flat list of strings. But based on the name of the string I would like to create either a nested list, a dictionary or a Node class. Anything that can have a tree structure

The string looks something like:

`['big_1', 'small_1', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'big_2', 'small_2', 'item_3']`

This should be turned into something like

```
['big_1', ['small_1', ['item_1', 'item_2']], 'big_2', ['small_2', ['item_3']]]
```

or a nested dictionary:

```
{'big_1': { 'small_1': ['item_1', 'item_2']}, 'big_2': {'small_2': ['item_3']}}
```

The example has 3 levels but it can be of any amount of levels. I tried something like this because that is not correct:

```
x = ['a_1', 'b_1', 'b_2', 'a_2', 'b_3', 'a_3', 'b_4', 'b_5', 'b_6']

def category(input):
    return input.split('_')[0]

cats = list(dict.fromkeys([category(i) for i in x])) # order preserved unique set
results = {}

prev_cat = ''
result = []
index = 0
for item in x:
    if index == 0:
        result.append(item)
        index += 1
        prev_cat = category(item)
    else:
        curr_cat = category(item)
        if curr_cat == prev_cat:
            # Same category, append
            result.append(item)
        else:
            result.append([item])
print(result)
```

It returns `['a_1', ['b_1'], ['b_2'], 'a_2', ['b_3'], 'a_3', ['b_4'], ['b_5'], ['b_6']]`

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What is the output you want for you to give an input example? It is really hard to translate your general syntax example to your specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to achieve this using recursion.

```py
x = ["big_1", "small_1", "item_1", "item_2", "big_2", "small_2", "item_3"]


def category(input):
    return input.split("_")[0]


def parse(l):
    out = []
    cat = category(l[0])
    sublist = []
    for el in l:
        if category(el) != cat:
            sublist.append(el)
        else:
            if len(sublist) > 0:
                out.append(parse(sublist))
                sublist = []
            out.append(el)
    if len(sublist) > 0:
        out.append(parse(sublist))
        sublist = []
    return out


print(parse(x))
```

Basically what I do is recursively call the `parse` function each time I find a different level. The code is just a test and can definitely be improved.